# Смотреть кино- примыкание?

Tags: синтаксис

Смотреть кино- примыкание?

Comment: На последнем ряду - обязательно.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, управление.Смотреть кого? что?-вин. падеж. Примыкают неизменяемые ЧАСТИ РЕЧИ+неизменяемые прилагательные и формы ЕГО,ЕЁ,ИХ.

Comment: А ксли "пошел ***кино смотреть***"?
Может управляемое слово быть перед управляющим?

Кстати, а чем "ЕГО,ЕЁ,ИХ" лучше "мой" "твой" "свой"? Разве тип грамматической связи определяется не свойствами "первого" слова в этой связи, а (не)изменяемостью "второго"?

Comment: Именно так, зависимым словом по отношению к  ГЛАВНОМУ( Не к  ПЕРВОМУ)Порядок слов может быть и прямой, и обратный. А вот формы  ЕГО,ЕЁ,ИХ не могут входить в сочетание с согласованием, т.к.при изменении падежа главного слова они не меняют свою падежную форму, т.е. не согласуются, они примыкают, т.е. НЕЗАВИСИМО определяют существительное: моя шляпа-моей шляпы, но её шляпа-её шляпы-её шляпой-о её шляпе.-примыкание. В случае с кино форма неизменяемая, но падеж всё-таки определяется - вин. и отношения объектные, а не определительные, как в примыкании. А вот видел кого?-его,её, их - управление.

Answer (score 2):

Определите главное (я его наберу ЗАГЛАВНЫМИ буквами) и зависимое слово: СМОТРЕТЬ кино.
Определите, какой частью речи зависимое слово выражено: кино(сущ.)
Если зависимое слово - неизменяемая часть речи (наречие, деепричастие или начальная форма глагола, т.е. инфинитив, отвечает на вопрос ЧТО (С)ДЕЛАТЬ?), то перед Вами примыкание.
Если зависимое слово выражено любой другой частью речи, то  поставьте его в другую форму: СМОТРЮ кино
Управление заставляет зависимое слово стоять по стойке "смирно!" (т.е. зависимое слово не изменяется)СМОТРЕТЬ кино  СМОТРЮ кино МОЕ кино
Согласование изменяет и зависимое слово

Вывод- это управление)

Answer (score 1):

Основная загвоздка - само управляемое слово имеет неизменяемую форму. Но в различных ситуациях оно может стоять в разных падежах.
Насладился (чем) итальянским кино.
Рассказал (о чем) о вчерашнем кино.
В сочетании с глаголом *смотреть* возможен только В.п. :
Смотрел (что) кино; смотрел (на что) на кино, как на вредную забаву; смотрел (сквозь что) сквозь кино, не видя ничего...
Управление.