# ЕГЭ (о типах грамматической связи)

Tags: синтаксис

Одно из заданий по подготовке к ЕГЭ по тексту Мамина-Сибиряка:  **Укажите тип подчинительной связи в словосочетании ЕГО ПОЯВЛЕНИЕ (предложение 38)**. 
Речь идёт о появлении офени: (**38) Для нас, детей, его появление в доме являлось настоящим праздником.**

Какой же правильный ответ?

Comment: Есть о чем поспорить. За это - плик.

Comment: Появление ЕГЭ - многих сильно огорчило...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос отличный.
Существительное ПОЯВЛЕНИЕ управляет личным местоимением ЕГО.  А вот есть ли у местоимения ЕГО в этом примере значение притяжательности?

У **отглагольных** существительных **среднего рода** (!) не может быть зависимого слова со значением притяжательности, принадлежности. Элен права. Ср.: его (личное местоимение в значении притяжательного, связь примыкание) шляпа, увидел его (предметное значение, связь управление), но: его появление (?). 
К притяжательным относят лишь местоимения МОЙ, ТВОЙ, НАШ, ВАШ, СВОЙ. Они действительно согласуются с определяемым существительным - связь согласование. 
Но местоимения ЕГО, ИХ, ЕЁ - личные. Они могут употребляться В ЗНАЧЕНИИ притяжательных с сущ-ми, ОБОЗНАЧАЮЩИМИ ПРЕДМЕТ, ЛИЦО, и ***не согласуются*** с этими существительными-связь примыкание. 
У нас ПОЯВЛЕНИЕ - отглагольное существительное среднего рода. Принадлежность исключается. ЕГО - это личное местоимение-существительное (появление КОГО?), хотя вопрос ЧЬЁ? мы тоже в таких случаях легко формулируем по аналогии с вопросами к притяжательным местоимениям. 
**Я за управление.**

Comment: >Но местоимения ЕГО, ИХ, ЕЁ   
  
А ничего, что они тоже отвечают на вопрос "чей?"

Врочем, согласен с тем, что тут есть грамматическая омонимия. "Появление чье" против "появление кого".
"Появление его и тебя". Или "его и твое появление".  

Т.е. "Его появление" формально может быть аналогом для третьего лица сочетаний "тебя появление" и "твое появление". В первом случае можно было бы говорить об управлении. Но уж очень вычурно получается при таком порядке слов. Все-таки тут "чье", а не "кого". Посему - все мной сказанное - в силе.

Answer (score 2):

Хороший вопрос, однако...  Помнится, уже был спор на эту тему... Увы, компромисса мы тогда не достигли.

Школьная грамматика (вроде бы?) все еще считает связь с участием неизменяемых притяжательных местоимений *примыканием*. Наверное, это вошло и в ЕГЭ.

Но на мой вкус идет явная профанация. В числе притяжательных местоимений всего три неизменяемых (его, её и их). Все остальные - благополучно себе изменяются. Не странно ли после этого считать связь для этих трех случаев - примыканием, а для всех остальных - согласованием?

Для сравнения. По этой логике получается, что "надеть шляпу" - управление, а "надеть пальто" - примыкание.
А если "надеть пальто и шляпу"? Или, возвращаясь к нашему примеру, "его и твое появление"?

Хоть застрелите меня, по всей логике и в исходный случай должен быть признан *согласованием*.
тут надо различать случаи, когда в любое слово в зависимой позиции принципиально не изменяется (требует инфинитива, скажем) и когда в этой позиции стоит слово, у которого все падежные (личные?) формы совпадают.

//-----------------------
Предыдущий разговор на тему притяжательных местоимений и вида связи:
[Смотреть кино- примыкание?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/24720)

К сожалению, ничего путного в плане понимания...

Comment: Нет, согласованием тут и не пахнет. При согласовании зависимое слово изменяется вместе с главным.  А вот насчёт управления...
Мне это местоиение не кажется прияжательным. Оно заменяет в данном случае не притяжательное прилагательное, а существительное "офеня". "Офени появление" вы тоже отнесёте к примыканию?

Comment: >При согласовании зависимое слово изменяется вместе с главным. А вот насчёт управления... 

Так оно и "меняется". Просто все падежи у него одинаковы. 

Сранивте: "Твое и его" появление, "Твоего и его появления", "Твоему и его появлению". Ну не виновата грамматика, что все падежи у слова "его" совпадают.
Я же аналогию с пальто приводил. "Надеть пальто" - примыкание?  

//--------------------------

ЗЫ Дерзкий, повторяю, я с Вами общаться не намерен.

Answer (score 1):

*Его появление*.
В данном случае зависимым словом является притяжательное местоимение **его**. Оно не изменяется, следовательно, подчинительная связь - **примыкание**.
http://www.gramma.ru/EXM/?id=4.38
Указанный ресурс очень строго заботится о своих авторских правах, поэтому небольшая цитата из грамма.ру в комментарии будет вскоре удалена, дабы не нарушать **их правила**.

Нашел очень интересную ссылку с подробным разбором и обоснованием.
http://www.rus-exam.ru/journal/articles/item/225-v3-razbor
Приводится также пример противоположного анонимно-чиновного мнения. Есть опасение больших конфликтных ситуаций на экзаменах.
Ходишь, ходишь в школу, а потом - бац! - правила прямо на экзамене поменяли...
Классификация подчинительных связей в своем малюсеньком и малопринципиальном моменте (его, ее, их) должна быть официально оглашена и утверждена, прежде чем подобные спорные задания чиновники будут вставлять... куда-то будут их вставлять...
(задумчиво) Мне очень жаль учащихся, которые вынуждены искать неочевидную истину не в классической Русской Грамматике, а на форумах, подобных нашему. Причем вопрос-то явно тенденциозный, куда оглобли поворотишь, туда и выедешь.
Проще запретить притяжательность *его*, *ее* и примкнувших к ним *их*.
Но я за традицию, за **примыкание**.

Comment: >Особое внимание следует обратить на
словосочетания с притяжательными
местоимениями **его, ее, их** : они, в отличие
от омонимичных им форм личных
местоимений, не изменяются и,
соответственно, вступают только в **связь
примыкание**.

Comment: Офенино появление или появление офени в вопросе не разбираются. Мы говорим о местоимении. В контексте ("Для нас, детей, его появление в доме являлось {тут нет тавтологии??} настоящим праздником") порядок слов подразумевает вопрос - чье появление? Не появление кого (их, лебедих), а чье-то появление. Чудесное его появление. Притяжательность здесь несомненна, иначе зачем они, притяж. местоимения, существуют?  
Его товар, его появление, его исчезновение.

Comment: Поясню маленький нюанс.  
Появление (кого) *его* в доме. Кто-то (он) пришел в дом. Акцент - на  человека, который **ОН**. Мы себе представляем офеню, зашедшего поторговать мелочишкой. 
*Его* (чье) появление в доме. Акцент - на "волшебное" явление, которое сопровождается праздником для детей, что-то типа Рождества или даже больше. Здесь мы видим веселую кутерьму вокруг "его ПОЯВЛЕНИЯ" со всеми криками, ахами, вздохами и разбором офениных прибамбасов.

Answer (score 1):

Притяжательные местоимения ЕГО, ЕЕ, ЕГО (дом, дача, имение), по происхождению застывшие  формы Род.п. указательных местоимений И(м.р.), Я(ж.р.), Е(ср.р.) со значением принадлежности, в современном русском языке имеют некоторые особенности:

1) у этих местоимений --- собственное значение ГРАММАТИЧЕСКОГО РОДА: ЕГО (м.р.) ---дом (м.р.), дача (ж.р.), имение (ср.р.) Мужской род ЕГО соотносится с родом имени-названия предмета, на который указывает это местоимение: ЕГО --> м.р. отца, брата, тестя, друга и т.п. То же у местоимений: ЕЕ(ж.р.), ЕГО(ср.р.);

2) у этих местоимений --- собственное значение ЧИСЛА: ЕГО (ед.ч.) --- дом(ед.ч.), дома(мн.ч), ИХ (мн.ч для всех родов) --- дома (мн.ч), дом(ед.ч). Единственное и множественное число местоимений соотносятся с числом имени-предмета/предметов, на который/которые указывает местоимение: ЕГО ---> отца (ед.ч.), брата (ед.ч.), друга(ед.ч.) и т.п.,  то же у местоимений ЕЕ (ж.р.) и ЕГО(ср.р.); ИХ ---> отцов(мн.ч.), братьев(мн.ч.), друзей (мн.ч.)и т.л.;

3) по ПАДЕЖАМ притяжательные местоимения не изменяются  (это застывшие формы Родительного падежа -- см. выше):

И.п. ЕГО дом

Р.п. ЕГО домА

Д.п. ЕГО домУ  и т.д.

ВЫВОД. Притяжательные местоимения ЕГО, ЕЕ, ЕГО, ИХ ПРИМЫКАЮТ к определяемому слову. Их подчиненность главному слову выражается лексически и порядком слов.

Answer (score 0):

ЕГО ПОЯВЛЕНИЕ - это словосочетание со связью управление, так как в школьной грамматике считается, что формы местоимений ЕЁ, ЕГО,  ИХ - могут, в зависимости от контекста, быть и личными (она, он, они) в родительном(винительном) падеже, и притяжательными, отвечающими на вопросы ЧЬЯ? ЧЕЙ? ЧЬИ?
Если мы говорим о его появлении, значит можно сказать появление КОГО? его (ОН появился), так как нет объекта принадлежности, появление ему НЕ принадлежит (просто он появился).
Вот если бы вещи были ЕГО, то можно было бы сказать вещи - ЧЬИ? - его (они ему принадлежат), и тогда местоимение ЕГО было бы притяжательным, и соответственно, вид связи был бы примыкание.